# Cucumber Extent Report - Capture screenshot and add exception log

Tags: java, cucumber, extentreports

I had tried to search on internet about capture screenshot and add exception to extent report when fail but not could understand.

What is the difference between spark and html report?

Hope someone can provide example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cucumber with protractor, you can attach screenshot on failed scenario step you can use it like this

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { After } from 'cucumber';

After(async function (scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        const screenshot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using cucumber with selenium java.

Comment: Anyone can provide an example?